# SyncedSideBar on Atom IDE

Tags: ide, sublimetext3, atom-editor

Is there away to install **SyncedSideBar** or something similar to that for Atom IDE ?

I used this [one](https://github.com/TheSpyder/SyncedSideBar) on my sublime text 3, and I was looking for the same plugin that will work for Atom.

I like how it auto highlight the current `opened` file

[image]

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any extra plugin for this. It there in the default tree plugin. Search for `tree` in packages

[image: Tree package]

Click on settings and check the `Auto Reveal` checkbox

[image: Auto reveal check]

And now the active file will be automatically highlighted

[image: Auto revealed tree]

Some of the themes may not highlight this properly, so you should change the theme and make sure it works. Sometimes after changing the settings you may need a restart, if it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will go ahead and test this suggested soltion tonight, and if work, will accept.

Comment: You saved my life. I've been looking for this for weeks.

Comment: And surprisingly I have installed Atom just few hours back :-). I mostly  use Sublime only

Comment: Wow. Atom is fast when lighter, and faster compare to ST 3.